# Picasso and Android dev advice

Tags: android, picasso

My question is simple. I am currently using Picasso, however I saw there was a tutorial about how to load bitmaps efficiently. (https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Do I need to take care about that or Picasso manages everything?

Thank you

Comment: Picasso will manage most of the thing for you. You still need to use correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It manages it for you. Their tutorials is all you need to follow.